# Python: values doesnt get assigned

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix

```
Y_values = np.zeros([H2 - H1, W2 - W1], dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(H1, H2):
    for j in range(W1, W2):
        Y_values[i - H1, j - W1] = (xyY_img[i, j, 2])
        print(Y_values)  #Returns zero
        print(xyY_img)   #Returns returns proper values
        print(xyY_img.shape) #(480, 512, 3)
```

I am not able to assign 3rd index values of `xyY_img` in `Y_values`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: might be related to how python's range omits the endpoint

Comment: What's `xyY_img.dtype`?

Comment: post a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting question is, in what range are the values you want to assing to `Y_values`. If they are in `[0,1)` then you will not see any changes in your array, since all the values will be casted to integers and numbers below 1 will naturally be casted to 0.

So if you can provide us with more information we might be able to provide you with the help you need.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.